# Seeing strange things in light

Tags: vision

I have noticed that if you look directly at tubelight (I have only white ones in my home) and close your eyes little, you see little random shaped colourless things sometimes with slow speed and sometimes with falling down.

They are shaped like circles with something in between and in chains of random length.

My father has also seen them. So, I am sure I am not imagining things. What the hell are they?

Comment: They're inside your eyes ;)

Comment: Oh, John Rennie's answered that. My bad, didn't see!

Comment: Almost everyone has these and they are harmless in small numbers. If you have a *sudden increase* in the number of floaters then that is symptomatic of potentially serious problems and you should consult an eyecare professional.

Comment: It's been suggested that this is off topic here and belongs on [biology.SE].

Comment: This was an enigma to me from my birth to yet.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Those are [floaters](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Floater). These are objects floating in the vitreous humour that fills the eyeball. They typically look like:

[image: Floaters]

Comment: Thanks. Up until now, I knew that it were white blood cells.. :)

Comment: @SachinShekhar They're a variety of stuff. Protein structures, cell debris, etc.

Comment: Wikipedia says *in old age*.Is it normal for a 15 year old kid to see them?

Comment: @Awesome: Have you tried Googling to find out? Given that this is a physics site I doubt there are many experts on eye health hereabouts.

Comment: Oh... my bad... happens when you study too much chemistry ... Thanks.

Comment: @Awesome: I've seen them ever since I was a little kid, so I don't think it's abnormal.

Comment: I've seen them since a young age too so probably nothing to worry about. (Sorry this was supposed to be a response to the existing answer, I can't see how to move it.)

Comment: @Awesome I can recall being fascinated by this when I was still in my cot - probably about 3 years old. I recall quivverring my eyes to make them move around! I'm now 50 and everything sight wise still works well!

Answer (score 1):

In https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Blue_field_entoptic_phenomenon this phenomenon is explained with white blood cells in your retina.