# What are these tiny, almost transparent, dots in my vision?

Tags: eyes

Sometimes when I stare at a very bright thing such as the sky I see little dots. It's actually more of a circle with a little dot inside it. They are half-transparent and they move around a lot. When I first see them they tend to appear in a group out of nowhere. I have seen one that is gray and almost black. What is this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are probably seeing [**floaters**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Floater).

> [Floaters](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Floater) are deposits of various size, shape, consistency, refractive index, and motility within the eye's vitreous humour, which is normally transparent. At a young age, the vitreous is transparent, but as one ages, imperfections gradually develop

[image]

You might as well be seeing [**Scheerer's phenomenon**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Blue_field_entoptic_phenomenon)

> [The blue field entoptic phenomenon or Scheerer's phenomenon](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Blue_field_entoptic_phenomenon) [..] is the appearance of tiny bright dots (nicknamed blue-sky sprites) moving quickly along squiggly lines in the visual field, especially when looking into bright blue light such as the sky.

[image]

Please have a look at the wikipedia article for more information.

I only now realize that your question is a duplicate of [Seeing strange things in light](https://biology.stackexchange.com/questions/16905/seeing-strange-things-in-light)